# No controls are displayed for JCE on front-end

Tags: joomla, joomla-content-editor

I've gone through all the tutorials and read through a ton of forum posts, but to no avail. I cannot get JCE to work properly on the front-end of my Joomla project.

I have the group settings to allow Editors (and higher levels) to use JCE. When I login as an editor on the front-end though, I only have text boxes to edit the content, no controls.

I've tried re-installing, running upgrades, replacing editor.js and toggle.js files, and clearing my cache (I even tried from a completely separate computer that never saw the site before, so it had no cache from the site).

Nothing seems to be working. I'm running the latest version of JCE (just tried re-installing off of 'com_jce_157_154_package.zip') and I'm running Joomla v1.5.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you dont't have any javascript conflicts. If you are using extra javascript libraries like jQuery or prototype, disable them temporarily and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure that your jQuery files are using jQuery.noConflict();. I had a similar problem in that another module's javascript was loaded before the JCE javascript & was causing a $ conflict scenario.

Also, try to manually enable one of the members of said groups to have JCE as the default editor - does that help?